# Game with probability

Tags: probability

Consider the following game: There are 3 white balls and 4 black balls in a black box. If you get a white ball out your payoff +1, and -1 with a black ball. You can stop anytime and repeat the game infinite times. Will you play the game? If yes, then what is your strategy ?

This is from an interview. My first try is that, I compute the expectation of payoff when I pick 1, 2,...7 balls. Namely let X be the event that I pick X balls from the black box. Then

E[X=1]= 1 *3/7+ (-1)*4/7=-1/7;

E[X=2]=1*(3/7)*(2/6)+ (-1) (4/7)(3/6) <0 ... We know that E[X=k], k=1,2,..,7 are negative, so we should not play the game ?

Is that correct ?

Thanks

Comment: You made the error of assuming that your available strategies are deciding before the game ever begins how many balls you will pull in total.  Your strategy can be more complicated however and decisions can be made in the middle of the game based on current results.

Answer (score 0):

definitely you should play it.

consider a simple strategy:

for the first two draws, once you get white, stop and start a new one

if not, then you get two black, just finish it all.